# What's this text encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, gmail, character, imaplib

I used Python's imaplib to pull mail from a gmail account... but I got an email with this confusing text body:

```
> RGF0ZSBldCBoZXVyZTogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAyMi8wOC8yMDEwIDE0
> OjMzOjAzIEdNVCBVbmtub3duDQpQcsOpbm9tOiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
> ICAgICAgICAgamFjaW50bw0KTm9tOiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
> ICAgICBjYXJ2YWxobw0KRS1NYWlsOiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
```

who can help me to read this file from my email...

Thx

lo

Comment: btw check the headers, are you sure there wasn't a `Content-Encoding: base64` header in there somewhere?

Comment: @Piskvor - There won't be one because it was actually prefixed with `>` indicating that it was quoted reply text.  Either it's badly written spam, or some badly coded email client didn't un-base64 it before quoting it in the reply.

Comment: @Omnifarious: good point, didn't notice that. Could be any of that, yeah.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like base64. In Python you can either use [`base64.b64decode`](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) or [`str.decode('base64')`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode).

```
message = '''
RGF0ZSBldCBoZXVyZTogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAyMi8wOC8yMDEwIDE0
OjMzOjAzIEdNVCBVbmtub3duDQpQcsOpbm9tOiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgamFjaW50bw0KTm9tOiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICBjYXJ2YWxobw0KRS1NYWlsOiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
'''

print message.decode('base64')
```

Result:

```
Date et heure:                           22/08/2010 14:33:03 GMT Unknown
PrÃ©nom:                                   jacinto
Nom:                                     carvalho
E-Mail:
```

The `Ã©` looks like it is incorrect. It appears that the text was encoded in UTF-8, so you also need to decode the UTF-8 encoding:

```
print message.decode('base64').decode('utf-8')
```

Result:

```
...
Prénom:
...
```

One other thing to be aware of is that there are different variants of Base64 encodings that differ in the two symbols they use for value 62 and 63. Using `base64.b64decode` you can specify these two characters if the defaults don't work for you.

Comment: OP kinda got lucky it didn't have any usernames/passwords in there :)

Answer (score 1):

Mark is mostly correct, but it is also UTF-8 encoded as evidenced by the `\uc3a9` in "Prénom".

(And I'm trying to figure out why I get a proper decoding and Mark doesn't for the same code, but that's another issue.)

Comment: Maybe your terminal is set to UTF-8 by default?

Comment: @Mark: aye, 'twas it (learn something everyday (and my mother said all that time spent forging passports would never do me any good...))

Answer (score 1):

It's Base-64 UTF-8. This particular text says:

```
Date et heure:                           22/08/2010 14:33:03 GMT Unknown
Prénom:                                   jacinto
Nom:                                     carvalho
E-Mail:
```